# Uniformly Convergent Power Series Bounded Operators

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, uniform-convergence

I am given a bounded operator *T* on a Hilbert space *H* with $\left\vert \left\vert{T}\right\vert \right\vert < 1$. I am trying to show that
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\begin{array} 11/2\\ n\end{array}\right)T^n
\end{align*}
converges uniformly to $(I + T)^{1/2}$ satisfying $((I + T)^{1/2})^2 = I + T$. I am not sure how to get uniform convergence for this. I tried running through the definition of uniform convergence, but was unable to to get it. I tried looking back to undergraduate analysis and consider the function $f(x) := \sqrt{1 + x}$, but I was unable to get any inspiration from this. I would appreciate any suggestions, ideas, or anything at all.

Comment: How about proving it converges uniformly to $(I-T/2)^{-1}$ instead?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown forgive me, but how would that help?

Comment: It would help because it does converge to $(I-T/2)^{-1}$, which is not likely to equal $(I+T)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}2^{-k}T^{k}\| \leq \sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\|2^{-k}T^{k}\|\leq \sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}2^{-k} \to 0$ as $ n >m \to \infty$. hence the partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}T^{k}$ form a Cauchy sequence in the space of bounded operators on $H$ with the operator norm. Since this space is complete it follows that the series converges to a bounded operator $S$. Now just verify that $(I-\frac T 2) S=S(I-\frac T 2)=I$.

Answer for the revised question: the proof is similar. The series $\sum |\binom {\frac 1 2} {n}||x|^{n}$ converges for $|x| <1$. Hence $\sum \|\binom {\frac 1 2} {n}T^{n}\| <\infty$ and we can prove,as before, that the series $\sum \binom {\frac 1 2} {n}T^{n}$ converges to a bounded operator.

Comment: I accidentally wrote the problem incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance @KaviRamaMurthy.